# How to check if link is visible for a user on remote site?

Tags: php, html, curl, hyperlink

I'm trying to check if link is available on remote url. My tool checks link presence on remote website and its anchor text via curl. 

But some links are placed in hidden blocks or outside of visible area, or have the same color as background, so users can't see them.
Is there way to check such visibility for users?

Comment: you will need to open it on your browser to do that. or you will have to read the css somehow

Comment: Probably not through any modest amount of programming effort.  Your best chance is to visit the site, do a VIEW SOURCE and look for the obvious suspects.  Bear in mind, too, that JavaScript can be used to obscure what is being shown on the web browser viewport, regardless of what you might find in the  HTML document!

Comment: This is the kind of thing Google has been trying to perfect for years, I think it will be very difficult if not hopeless to do accurately. Maybe some more context would help, you might have options other than the one you have already selected, depending on what your actual bottom-line goals are.

Comment: A straightforward approach would be to scrape a web-site by headless browser like PhantomJS, and then run OCR against the screenshot. It's doable even in pure PHP, but requires a lot of coding and finally will still be error-prone.